# Using bootstrap with phoenix: live_reload/frame

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, heroku, responsive-design, phoenix-framework

New to Phoenix and trying to use bootstrap in a template.  I have a responsive top nav that collapses with a hamburger menu (straightforward phoenix installation for heroku).

On my localhost, the button activates.  When I try it on my herokuapp, the button does not respond.

When I view source on localhost, I see this near the bottom (but not in production):
`<iframe src="/phoenix/live_reload/frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>`

Is this a likely culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<iframe src="/phoenix/live_reload/frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>` is part of the `phoenix_live_reload` hex package and does not get deployed to non-DEV environments, so this is expected.

Without further info I can only speculate about possible causes.  However, it seems the problem is related to your assets (JS and CSS).  It is possible you are not building them when building a release.  I would check that.